# How read an analogue input in R? / or how to translate an existing Matlab code

Tags: r, matlab, input

I use a photoelectric cell to time an event in a response time experiment. It works well in Matlab, but I wanted to control it in R. Would any of you be able to help me translate the Matlab code to R?

```
global AI ch0
AI = analoginput('nidaq', 1);
AI.InputType = 'SingleEnded';
ch0 = addchannel(AI,0);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you not like about Matlab? Why do you need this in R?

Comment: More than likely the experiment is also being run in Matlab.  Matlab therefore contains all your variables like the time at which you issued the stimulus presentation and such.  Keeping this in Matlab and then exporting it all together so that R can read it is your best bet here.

Comment: R isn't a language like Matlab or Python that you could actually do an arbitrary RT experiment in.  It's not a language property per se, merely a consequence of implementation.  But it won't be changed.  Just use R for your data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. @ Hamish for various reasons that I should probably not go into here. It's not a problem with Matlab per se.

Answer (score 2):

You could play around with the R.matlab package. This allows you to read your MAT files in R, so you could simply save the input and analyse it in R. Alternatively, you could interact directly between Matlab and R. I didn't try it out before, but it should be possible to call the matlab code from within R. The provided manual on CRAN shows you how.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called windmill:

http://www.windmill.co.uk/index.html

(windows only I think) that interacts with serial devices, you could probably use that to get the information from your device to a file or pipe and then have R read from there.

You could also do a search for "gps" at rseek or in the R-help archives, there have been a few times that people have posted questions and answers about reading location information directly from gps devices into R, some of those replies may work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

R does not support any kind of direct interaction with DAQ devices (at least for now). The only option you have is to write some C code to do this and bind it to R.

Comment: Or alternatively in Python + SciPy.

Comment: @Hamish If you think about ctyping niDAQ library, it is equivalent job to the hack that has to be done with R.

Comment: it depends on how complicated the needs are.
http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Data_Acquisition_with_NIDAQmx
For a real-time system it might be worthwhile grabbing data using a C module running atop RTLinux, then spitting it out to a file located on in-ram file system, then letting another program like Python+SciPy process it (as long as it can keep up with the buffer of data that is being collected).

Answer (score 1):

Write National Instruments and ask them to make an R package for their I/O devices.  :)

Comment: They would have said it about Mac support in the at the turn of the century. :)  - (former NI junkie who will never touch the stuff again)

Comment: Don't want to be the party pooper, but shouldn't this be a comment?